# Django,TypeError: context must be a dict rather than set

Tags: python, django, type-error

Если убрать  {'form', form} то все работает.

**views.py**

```
...
def add_news(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        pass
    else:
        form = NewsForm()
    return render(request, 'bord/add_news.html', {'form', form})
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Category


class NewsForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    content = forms.CharField()
    is_published = forms.BooleanField()
    category = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Category.objects.all())
```

**add_news.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block sidebar %}
{% include 'inc/_sidebar.html' %}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<h1>Добавление новости</h1>

<form action="{% url 'add_news' %}" method="post">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Добавить новость</button>
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import *

urlpatterns = [
    path('', index, name='home'),
    # Создание переменной  category_id  с типом int, это число, которое передается через  url
    path('category/<int:category_id>/', get_category, name='category'),
    path('news/<int:news_id>/', view_news, name='view_news'),
    path('news/add-news/', add_news, name='add_news')
]
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: в тексте ошибки все написано. открывам документацию, читаем про рендер `Необязательные аргументы
context
Словарь переменных для контекста шаблона. По умолчанию, этот словарь пустой`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Исправьте:

```
return render(request, 'bord/add_news.html', {'form', form})
```

на

```
return render(request, 'bord/add_news.html', {'form': form})
```

`{a, b}` создает set из двух элементов. `{a: b}` - создает `dict` c одним элементом.

Comment: Спасибо , не заметил )